# React app runs locally but crashes on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I've spent 6+ hours trying to figure out why this won't run successfully on Heroku. It runs locally but when I deploy to Heroku I get the following log basically just saying the app crashed. I installed Heroku's CLI and tried to find a more helpful error in that but to no avail. Anyone else have any ideas or suggestions?

Code => https://github.com/ghughes13/react-todo-list

https://ghughes-react-todo-list.herokuapp.com/

```
2020-04-05T14:46:31.351885+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Project is running at http://172.18.176.170/
2020-04-05T14:46:31.355002+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: webpack output is served from 
2020-04-05T14:46:31.355159+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-04-05T14:46:31.355252+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: 404s will fallback to /
2020-04-05T14:46:31.355468+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-04-05T14:46:31.355470+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-05T14:46:31.498661+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-05T14:46:33.839876+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ghughes-react-todo-list.herokuapp.com request_id=199836cb-d38a-4941-aee7-fc5e5deba5dc fwd="97.99.41.155" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-04-05T14:46:34.454912+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ghughes-react-todo-list.herokuapp.com request_id=b905fff4-83bf-4319-801a-c2c4f1d7a4e1 fwd="97.99.41.155" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

```
  "name": "todo-list",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reach/router": "^1.3.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "mongodb": "^3.5.2",
    "mongodb-client-encryption": "^1.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.11",
    "reach": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: devDependencies are stripped out on Heroku. Also the dev server is (as the name suggests) for *dev*, not prod. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/41932041/3001761 for a minimal fix.

Comment: What do I have as a dev dependency?

Comment: How are you trying to host your react app? Deploying the webpack build folder as static content or running the app with node server on host?

Also, I suggest you to give a try to firebase. Sites always stay live unlike heroku, plus the deployment is easy.

Comment: I'm using heroku/nodejs as the buildpack. And sweet, I'll definitely look into firebase. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Garrett gave me good information about how I can fix it but did not explain how he fixed the situation clearly, I sent the link here in case you guys don't wanna struggle 1 more hour like me:

if you have react-app and have the same error changing your buildpack from basic heroku/node-js to create-react-app-buildpack will most likely fix it:

https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app-buildpack

on terminal/cmd:

```
   heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git#v6.0.0
```

then push your react-app again

Comment: You will first need to build the project with yarn build

Comment: @landrykapela No, you don't need to build your project before deployment. **Heroku** does that _automatically_ on deployment. it will build the project on your dyno based on the `package.json`. This buildpack helps heroku tailor the process specifically for reactjs. **However** , the _**Accepted Answer**_ requires that you prebuild your project before deployment as evident from `"start" : "serve -s build"`

Answer (score 4):

run

```
npm install --save serve
```

and then in your package.json change

```
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

to

```
"start": "serve -s build"
```

Actually, with the new version, there is a problem I don't know why. This is a workaround may be the fix it later

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like using heroku/nodejs for the build was causing the issue. Not sure why, because I've been slowly adding to this project for 2-3 months and it worked fine up until I added reach-router (But then when I removed reach router it still didn't work...).

Anyways changing the build pack to this fixed it: 
https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app.tgz