# MERN Stack with HEROKU DEPLOYMENT - APPLICATION ERROR

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, deployment, mern

I am trying to deploy my MERN stack (React, Express, NodeJS, Mongo) but I ran into an application error when I went to the site, though heroku said that it was successfully deployed. This is what was shown on my terminal.
Can someone help? Its my first time trying to deploy. [Terminal error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX4zX.png)

Comment: probably the script is missing but check out this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932041/create-react-app-deployment-to-heroku-failed-with-react-scripts-not-found) , it is same problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.